# How to set up handler for SSE misalignment exception?

Tags: c, winapi, exception, x86, sse

I am using mingw on win32..

I use signal() from c library that allow me to setup handler for some hardvare exceptions (like integer dib by zero, illegal operation etc) but it seems riight now that it not works for SSE misalignment exception (who do not go thru my handler but outa him and crashes app).

How to set such handler? I would like to show message box on such misalignment with at least "misaligned see acces" communicate, yet better with some additionel info..

How to do that?